# colorbox on a external link

Tags: entities, media, javascript

I have create a little fotogallery where I display only the first 3 images, the first "big" on the left side and the other two (small, width / 2 of the big one) on the right side. All images are "linked" to colorbox. 
If I click on one of these 3 images colorbox "run" (ok, perfect).

Via a div in a absolute position style I have added this phrase "See all NUMBER images". Now I need to link this "phrase" to the event that run colorbox from the first image (the big).

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with jQuery `.trigger()` event.

```
jQuery('#id-of-your-phrase').click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 jQuery('#id-or-class-of-first-image-YouCanAlsoUse-first-child').trigger('click');
});
```

This code will open the colorbox from First Image (the Big).

Comment: Oh My god! So simple ? Why ??? Thanks and again thanks.